# Start Service on boot but not entire Android app

Tags: android, service, background, startup

I am working with Android.

I have an app I am working on uses an Activity to setup specific user input values that are then used by a service to provide alerts based on those values. Doing the research I determined how I could get the app to start up when the phone boots, however, what I really want is to have the service start but not have the app load to the screen. Currently the entire app loads to the screen when I turn on the device and then I have to exit out of it.

I have downloaded similar programs that have interfaces for settings but otherwise run in the background. How is that done?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am working with Android. Specifically API 10.

Comment: Post some code. You implemented a BroadcastReceiver (I assume), but what exactly are you doing in the `onReceive`? context.startService()?

Comment: You should simply not add any content to your Application Object, and keep your service slim...(do not start any BL from these). I'm not really sure how much function of the app you can keep up, but this would get what you want. Perhaps a notification could start an activity with your BL content...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you have to create a receiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final static String TAG = "BootCompletedReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.w(TAG, "starting service...");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
    }
}
```

Then add permission to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and register intent receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After this is done, your application (`Application` class) will run along with services, but no Activities.

Ah, and don't put your application on SD card (APP2SD or something like that), because it has to reside in the main memory to be available right after the boot is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You confirmed for me that I was actually doing the correct thing. The reason that it wasn't working was that the service required data from the Activity which was not available until the Activity started. However, I have come up with a work around. Much appreciated!